Range centered at mean of a normal distribution
The weight, in grams, of a product manufactured has a normal distribution $N(20,4)$.
I have to find the range, centered at mean, given in grams, for which the probability of $0.899$ that the weight of a randomly selected unit is contained within it.
Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$P(20-c\leq X\leq20+c)=0.899\Rightarrow 2\cdot P(X\leq20+c)=0.899$$
i.e.,
$$P(X\leq20+c)=0.4495$$
From $N(0,1)$ table, I found $Z=1.64$. Hence,
$$X=\mu+\underbrace{Z\cdot\sigma}_{c}\Rightarrow X=20+1.64\cdot4$$
Therefore,
$$c=6.56$$
and then, the range is
$$20-6.56\leq X\leq20+6.56\Rightarrow 13.44\leq X\leq26.56$$
which means, the unity must have a weight between $13.44$ and $26.56$ grams.

You've got some errors. The statement
$$\Pr(20 - c \leq X \leq 20 + c) = 0.899 \implies 2 \Pr(X \leq 20 + c) = 0.899$$
is wrong.
$$2 \Pr(X \leq 20 + c) > \Pr(X \leq 20 + c) > \Pr(20 - c \leq X \leq 20 + c)$$
so
$$\Pr(20 - c \leq X \leq 20 + c) = 0.899 \implies 2 \Pr(X \leq 20 + c) \neq 0.899$$
Instead, note
$$X \sim \mathsf{Normal}(20, 4) \implies \frac{X - 20}{2} \sim \mathsf{Normal}(0, 1)$$
so
\begin{aligned}
\Pr\left( -c \leq \frac{X - 20}{2} \leq c \right) = 0.899 &\iff 2 \Pr\left( \frac{X - 20}{2} \leq - c \right) = 1 - 0.899 \\
&\iff \Pr\left( \frac{X - 20}{2} \leq - c \right) = 0.0505
\end{aligned}
which we can look up in a table to find $c = 1.64$. Therefore,
$$\Pr \left( -1.64 \leq \frac{X - 20}{2} \leq 1.64 \right) = \Pr\left( 16.72 \leq X \leq 23.28\right) = 0.899$$

But it doens't make sense to have $-16.72$ grams.

Sorry, you're right. The negative sign shouldn't have been there. I removed it.

I just realized I used $\sigma=4$ instead of $\sigma=2$.
